# "make" gives a executable

Tags: c, linux, makefile

I am new in Makefile. I have wrote hello.c and when I do "make hello" then it gives executable named as "hello". Internally it showing "cc hello.c -o hello". But without Makefile how make works? How make is gives executable as same name as source?

Comment: Make has a number of [built-in rules](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Catalogue-of-Rules.html), it will use those unless a Makefile overrides them.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

make has a database of built in rules. These rules include recipes for a number of common operations.

The GNU Make Manual covers (some at least) of these recipes in the [Catalogue of Built-Inf Rules](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Catalogue-of-Rules) section.

Additionally, the output from the [`-p`/`--print-data-base`](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#index-_002dp) option will show you all of the rules/recipes and variables that make has built-in.

Answer (score 0):

the make command of your compiler will, if no further arguments are given and no makefile is present, use default parameters. Default parameters are, in the case of your `hello.c` (a normal c file) and your compiler settings (presumably fresh from install) to make an executable with the same name as the input file.

Thats just how the compiler is made.

Comment: If you dont have a makefile, your compiler just assumes you want an executeable of the same name as the file.

Comment: If your question is answered, accept one answer as the official answer by clicking on the little checkbox next to the answer score. I recommend you select Etain Reisner's Answer here, as it is the most explanative one currently.